# Which version of Spring is used in Grails 2.3.x

Tags: spring, grails

Is there an easy way to tell which exact version of Spring is the installed Grails using? Grails release notes don't seemd to have anything more than a hint by stating that it now supports Spring 3.1 profiles, so one could assume that it's at least 3.1.

Google did tell my that in earlier releases the lib/ dir contained Spring libs, where one could deduce the used version, but at least in my app, that dir is currently empty.

For the record, I'm getting an error on grails startup stating `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/objenesis/ObjenesisException`. A bit of googling gave me a hunch that this is due to my custom-made Spring component I'm trying to use in the Grails app. The Spring component has a dependency to Spring 4.0.5-RELEASE, which is probably causing the issue. I'd still like to know exactly which Spring version to use with the lib in order for it to be compatible.

**EDIT**

The NoClassDefFoundError can actually be worked around by adding excludes on the dependency like

compile('group:artifact:1.0') {
  excludes 'spring-aop', 'spring-context'
}

I'd still like to know the version of Spring Grails is using. Just to set the dependency to use the exact same for extra safety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get version, as well as versions for all other dependencies, by calling:

```
grails dependency-report
```